# Sqoop merge issue - Hortonworks

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I do have a primary key column on merge key attribute. Any help is greatly appricated

```
16/09/16 14:50:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1474053990963_0023_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot join values on null key. Did you specify a key column that exists?
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeMapperBase.processRecord(MergeMapperBase.java:79)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeTextMapper.map(MergeTextMapper.java:58)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeTextMapper.map(MergeTextMapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

Comment: Please show your sqoop command

Comment: @Mahesh Did you find the solution. I have the same issue. I have given the primary key as the merge column. But I am stil getting this error

Comment: @halbs which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution. I am using mysql db and the primary key in the table is defined in lowercase, but for the merge job I was giving the key in upper case. This was causing the issue. Once I gave the primary key in merge job in lower case the job ran successfully